# Como agrupar resultados numa linha?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Gostaria de realizar uma query Sobre a tabela FICHA_EXAME com os seguintes dados:

[image: ficha_exame]

```
CREATE TABLE FICHA_EXAME
(
 FICHA smallint,
 EXAME VARCHAR(15)
);

INSERT INTO FICHA_EXAME VALUES (1,'Hemograma');
INSERT INTO FICHA_EXAME VALUES (1,'Colesterol');
INSERT INTO FICHA_EXAME VALUES (1,'Ferro');
INSERT INTO FICHA_EXAME VALUES (2,'Colesterol');
INSERT INTO FICHA_EXAME VALUES (3,'Ferro');
INSERT INTO FICHA_EXAME VALUES (3,'Hemograma');
INSERT INTO FICHA_EXAME VALUES (4,'Ferro');
```

Na query que criei, gostaria que fosse exibido quais exames estão contidos na ficha extraída através de um "**Possui ou não Possui**", e não listar o exame de fato, porém gostaria que fosse exibida em apenas 1 linha.

Tentei da forma abaixo, mas para cada exame relacionado a ficha, me traz uma nova linha, e gostaria que fosse exibido dinamicamente em uma linha só, independente se houve mais de um exame igual na mesma ficha:

```
SELECT FICHA, 
      CASE WHEN EXAME = 'Hemograma' THEN 'S' ELSE 'N' END AS 'POSSUI HEMOGRAMA?',
      CASE WHEN EXAME = 'Colesterol' THEN 'S' ELSE 'N' END AS 'POSSUI COLESTEROL?',
      CASE WHEN EXAME = 'Ferro' THEN 'S' ELSE 'N 'END AS 'POSSUI FERRO?'
FROM FICHA_EXAME;
```

**Resultado**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso você vai precisar de um Pivot, caso tenha apenas estes três exames, pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT 
    FICHA, 
    CASE WHEN [Colesterol] IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'S' END AS [POSSUI COLESTEROL?], 
    CASE WHEN [Ferro] IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'S' END AS [POSSUI FERRO?], 
    CASE WHEN [Hemograma] IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'S' END AS [POSSUI HEMOGRAMA?] 
FROM FICHA_EXAME Ficha 
PIVOT (MAX(EXAME) FOR EXAME IN ([Hemograma], [Colesterol], [Ferro])) Colunas
```

Porém caso tenha um numero dinamico de exames, terá de montar o SQL para então executar o mesmo:

```
DECLARE @DinamicSQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
WITH CTE_EXAMEs AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT EXAME FROM FICHA_EXAME
), CTE_Indice AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EXAME) as EXAMEID, EXAME FROM CTE_EXAMEs
), CTE_Recur AS (
    SELECT 
        CTE_Indice.EXAMEID, 
        CAST('CASE WHEN [' + CTE_Indice.EXAME + '] IS NULL THEN ''N'' ELSE ''S'' END AS [POSSUI ' + UPPER(CTE_Indice.EXAME) + '?]' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS SqlColuna,
        CAST('[' + CTE_Indice.EXAME + ']' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS SqlPivot
    FROM CTE_Indice
    WHERE EXAMEID = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        CTE_Indice.EXAMEID, 
        CAST(CTE_Recur.SqlColuna + ', CASE WHEN [' + CTE_Indice.EXAME + '] IS NULL THEN ''N'' ELSE ''S'' END AS [POSSUI ' + UPPER(CTE_Indice.EXAME) + '?]' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS SqlColuna,
        CAST(CTE_Recur.SqlPivot + ', [' + CTE_Indice.EXAME + ']' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS SqlPivot
    FROM CTE_Indice
    JOIN CTE_Recur ON CTE_Indice.EXAMEID = CTE_Recur.EXAMEID + 1
), CTE_SQL AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CTE_Recur ORDER BY EXAMEID DESC
)


SELECT @DinamicSQL = 'SELECT FICHA, ' + SqlColuna + ' FROM FICHA_EXAME Ficha PIVOT (MAX(EXAME) FOR EXAME IN (' + SqlPivot + ')) Colunas'  FROM CTE_SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @DinamicSQL
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece pois o seu `CASE WHEN`  é executado para cada registro da tabela `FICHA_EXAME` então gera linhas diferentes pois ele está comparando valores diferentes. Uma forma de contornar o problema seria criando um SELECT para cada tipo de exame e fazer um JOIN. Segue abaixo o script que resolve seu problema:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fe.ficha, 
    COALESCE(h."Hemograma", 'N') AS 'POSSUI HEMOGRAMA?',
    COALESCE(c."Colesterol", 'N') AS 'POSSUI COLESTEROL?',
    COALESCE(f."Ferro",'N') AS 'POSSUI FERRO?'
FROM FICHA_EXAME fe
LEFT JOIN (SELECT FICHA, 'S' AS 'Hemograma' FROM FICHA_EXAME WHERE EXAME = 'Hemograma') as h
    on h.FICHA = fe.FICHA
LEFT JOIN (SELECT FICHA, 'S' AS 'Colesterol' FROM FICHA_EXAME WHERE EXAME = 'Colesterol') as c
    ON c.FICHA = fe.FICHA
LEFT JOIN (SELECT FICHA, 'S' AS 'Ferro' FROM FICHA_EXAME WHERE EXAME = 'Ferro') as f
    ON f.FICHA = fe.FICHA
ORDER BY 1;
```

Você pode filtrar também basta adicionar um `WHERE fe.FICHA = ?`

Answer (score 0):

Desta forma, obterá o nome dos exames dinamicamente. Portanto não precisará reescrever a consulta ao cadastrar um exame novo.

```
DECLARE @ColunasExt AS VARCHAR(MAX); SET @ColunasExt = 'SELECT FICHA, ';
DECLARE @ColunasInt AS VARCHAR(MAX); SET @ColunasInt = 'SELECT FICHA, '

/*Obtém dinamicamente o nome dos exames(colunas colunas sub interna)*/
SELECT @ColunasInt = @ColunasInt + '(CASE WHEN MAX(EXAME) = '''+(EXAME)+ ''' THEN ''S'' ELSE ''N'' END) AS [POSSUI '+EXAME+' ?], '
FROM FICHA_EXAME GROUP BY EXAME
/*Retira a última vírgula*/
SET     @ColunasInt = SUBSTRING(@ColunasInt,1,LEN(@ColunasInt)-1)
SET @ColunasInt = @ColunasInt + ' FROM FICHA_EXAME GROUP BY FICHA,EXAME'

/*Obtém dinamicamente o nome dos exames(colunas colunas sub externa)*/
SELECT @ColunasExt = @ColunasExt + 'MAX([POSSUI '+EXAME+' ?]) AS [POSSUI '+EXAME+' ?], '
FROM FICHA_EXAME GROUP BY EXAME
/*Retira a última vírgula*/
SET     @ColunasExt = SUBSTRING(@ColunasExt,1,LEN(@ColunasExt)-1)
SET @ColunasExt = @ColunasExt + ' FROM ('+ @ColunasInt +')AS SUB GROUP BY SUB.FICHA' 

SELECT( @ColunasExt) /*Mostra o comando que foi montado*/
EXEC( @ColunasExt) /*Executa o comando que foi montado*/
```